# SharePoint 2010 profile synchronization AD to MOSS in BOTH Direction

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Our company want to setup a **User Profile Synchronization** on SharePoint 2010.

In **Manage User Properties** page, we can successfully configure a property to either import from AD to MOSS or export from MOSS to AD!

However, we want to configure some properties that allow synchronize in both direction, which is actual meaning of "Synchronize". We wonder if it was possible in MOSS 2010?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just to clarify, MOSS was the term used for SharePoint 2007.  Referring to 2010 as MOSS will only add confusion.  Microsoft just calls it SharePoint Server 2010 and SharePoint Foundation 2010.  Am I right that you use SharePoint Server 2010?

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty in your situation is for the system to know which is the source for the data.  If someone changes their phone number in AD and also in SharePoint, which is correct?  Usually some fields are set to have AD as their source and you set SharePoint to import.

And other fields are set to have SharePoint as the source and set SharePoint to export.  Setting both import and export on a field is a lot trickier because when the values don't match you need to have rules in place about how to figure out which is one wins.

Comment: Ok, so I have this exact same requirement.  I need to allow users to edit some props (such as phone number) using the SP 2010 Edit Profile page, and have it push to AD.

Then, there might be some other system that also updates AD user props (such as an HR system), and will change this property.  I would like to ensure that SP2010 will pick up that change from AD and update its own user profile with the new value.  I don't care which system is the one version of truth.  I care that if that property is changed in either one, that the other will sync up with it (a true sync).

Is that supported?

Answer (score 0):

No.  SharePoint 2010 User Profile Sync does not do 2-way sync, and cannot be configured to do so.